# Iterating over very large dataframe efficiency in python pandas is too time consuming

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bigdata

I am trying to iterate over 5million records in a csv. I am stuck with the following loop.

```
trajectory = 0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['trajectory'] == 'NaN':
        trajectory = trajectory +1
        df.loc[index, 'classification']= trajectory
    else:
        df.loc[index, 'classification'] = trajectory
```

When I come across 'NaN' in my DataFrame, I increase my value of trajectory and place the value into my 'classification' column.

I was trying of a smaller dataset, but when I run this code in my full .5 gig csv it takes hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compare with `NaN` if string and use [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
df['classification'] = (df['trajectory'] == 'NaN').cumsum() + trajectory
```

Or if `NaN` is missing value compare by [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.isnull.html):

```
df['classification'] = df['trajectory'].isnull().cumsum() + trajectory
```

**Timings**:

```
np.random.seed(2017)
L = ['s','a','NaN']
N = 1000
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'trajectory': np.random.choice(L, size=N)
})
#print (df)

trajectory = 0
def new(df, trajectory):
    df['classification'] = (df['trajectory'] == 'NaN').cumsum() + trajectory
    return df


def old(df, trajectory):
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if row['trajectory'] == 'NaN':
            trajectory = trajectory +1
            df.loc[index, 'classification']= trajectory
        else:
            df.loc[index, 'classification'] = trajectory
    return df
```

---

```
In [74]: %timeit (old(df, trajectory))
1 loop, best of 3: 609 ms per loop

In [75]: %timeit (new(df, trajectory))
1000 loops, best of 3: 928 µs per loop
```